# Prevent scroll to top on single router.navigate call in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

My Angular 8 app scrolls to top on navigating to new pages. On one specific page I have a sortable table. When navigating to that page it should scroll to top, but when a table header cell is clicked it should update the query params with the sort but **not** scroll to top.

Is it possible to call `router.navigate(...)` with the new query param data without triggering a scroll to top, while not disabling scroll to top from the route itself?

Answer (score 5):

You can configure router module with multiple options. You should be able to preserve scroll with [scrollPositionRestoration](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#scrollPositionRestoration) option.

You can use it like:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled' })
```

That being said this option will preserve scroll position for all pages.

If you want to achieve this only for a specific page, you have a choice to use [navigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) in your `navigate` call and specify current scroll position in [state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) object and upon `AfterViewInit` handler update scroll position.

Let's say you have a container which contains table, you can use `ViewChild` decorator to access it in component file.

```
// declare your container component
@ViewChild("container")
private container: ElementRef;

// after view init updated current scroll position
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const prevScrollPos = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state?.scrollTop;
  if (prevScrollPos) {
    this.container.nativeElement.scrollTop = prevScrollPos;
  }
}

// specify scroll position on navigation
this.router.navigate(
  ['/login'],
  {
    state: { scrollTop: this.container.nativeElement.scrollTop }
  }
);
```

Comment: I didn't have the time to test it, because the project turned to another direction; that lightbox branch will stay dormant for at least a week. But, your solution seems to be sound, though a bit hackish...actually it seems that angular completely lacks the ability to do it nicely. Thanks for your time and your effort writing such a nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the navigate() method returns a promise, you can scroll to a specific location once the promise resolves:

```
let currentScrollHeight = window.pageYOffset
this.router.navigate(['my-page']).then(() => window.scrollTo({ top: currentScrollHeight }))
```

Or if you are using rxjs like me, you can convert the Promise to an observable and do the same:

```
let currentScrollHeight = window.pageYOffset
from(this.router.navigate(['my-page'])).pipe(
  first(),
  tap(() => window.scrollTo({ top: currentScrollHeight }))
).subscribe()
```

This method doesn't produce any flickering/jumping on my machine which is what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on anchors, use a `@Viewchild` in combination with `block:'nearest'` to prevent the page from jumping to top:

```
@ViewChild("el") private el: ElementRef;

this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block:'nearest' });
```